# How to loop to find the average of variables by an ID variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr

I have a variable called student id and 45 variables starting with HY. They are showing the grades obtained for various subjects. I want to create a new variable by student id that shows the maximum grades obtained in 3 subjects divided by 3.

I can check the grades manually using:

```
df1 %>% group_by(student_id) %>% summarize(topgrade = max(HY_PR_marks_ENG:HY_PR_marks_Music)
```

By doing this, I fail to fulfill the objective of doing what I want. I am posting a sample of the data

```
structure(list(Student_ID = c("18R1044", "18R1055", "18R1064", 
"18R1075"), HY_PR_marks_ENG = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), HY_PR_marks_Paint = c("NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA"), HY_PR_marks_EG = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), 
    HY_PR_marks_Kathak = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), HY_PR_marks_Chem = c("26", 
    "22", "25", "NA"), HY_PR_marks_Phy = c("23.5", "23", "21", 
    "NA"), HY_PR_marks_Maths = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), HY_PR_marks_Bio = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA"), HY_PR_marks_Acc = c("NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "16"), HY_PR_marks_Econ = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "18"), HY_PR_marks_BST = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "17"), HY_PR_marks_PE = c("21", "21", "24", "21"
    ), HY_PR_marks_CS = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), HY_PR_marks_IP = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA"), HY_PR_marks_Music = c("NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA"), HY_WT_marks_ENG = c("11.5", "17.5", "17.5", "12.75"
    ), HY_WT_marks_Paint = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), HY_WT_marks_EG = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA"), HY_WT_marks_Kathak = c("NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA"), HY_WT_marks_Chem = c("12", "10.5", "15", "NA"), HY_WT_marks_Phy = c("3.5", 
    "7.5", "4", "NA"), HY_WT_marks_Maths = c("5.5", "11", "7", 
    "NA"), HY_WT_marks_Bio = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), HY_WT_marks_Acc = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "13.75"), HY_WT_marks_Econ = c("NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "18.33"), HY_WT_marks_BST = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "17.17"), 
    HY_WT_marks_PE = c("14", "19", "12", "14.5"), HY_WT_marks_CS = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA"), HY_WT_marks_IP = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"
    ), HY_WT_marks_Music = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), HY_TH_marks_ENG = c("62", 
    "74", "60.5", "72.5"), HY_TH_marks_Paint = c("NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA"), HY_TH_marks_EG = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), 
    HY_TH_marks_Kathak = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), HY_TH_marks_Chem = c("27.5", 
    "39.5", "41", "NA"), HY_TH_marks_Phy = c("8.5", "17.5", "37", 
    "NA"), HY_TH_marks_Maths = c("26", "29.5", "77", "NA"), HY_TH_marks_Bio = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA"), HY_TH_marks_Acc = c("NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "27"), HY_TH_marks_Econ = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "69.5"), HY_TH_marks_BST = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "64.5"), HY_TH_marks_PE = c("46", "56", "50", 
    "58"), HY_TH_marks_CS = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), HY_TH_marks_IP = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA"), HY_TH_marks_Music = c("NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA")), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Do you want the average or `max`.  Your code and description is confusing.  Can you show the expected output for the input data created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly and you want to identify the average of the best three grades per student, this should work:

```
df1 %>%
  #long format 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-Student_ID) %>%
  dplyr::filter(value!="NA") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>%
  # pick best three per Student_ID
  group_by(Student_ID) %>%
  arrange(desc(value), .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  dplyr::slice(1:3) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(topgrade = mean(value))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Student_ID topgrade
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 18R1044        45.2
2 18R1055        56.5
3 18R1064        62.5
4 18R1075        68.8
```